# Killall -9 inside docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Let's say I have 2 dockers, *dockerA* and *dockerB*, each running an instance of *program1*.

If I perform `killall -9 program1` inside *dockerA*, what happens to the program running inside *dockerB*? Does it keep running, or does it die?

Comment: it's simplicity itself to just try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep running inside dockerB

If you do `killall -9 program1` out of docker, on your machine, program1 still run inside dockerA and dockerB, killall will not have visibility between different machines.

You need to do something like this to have visibility: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E75728/html/section_rsr_p2z_fp.html

Answer (score 2):

The two containers are isolated so nothing happens in *dockerB*.